# React .map is not a function and solution

Tags: json, reactjs, dictionary, object

I have a really basic question about React map.
So I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "Status": true, 
  "discounts": {
    "individual": {
      "number_of_cars_discount": {
        "1": "1", 
        "10": "1", 
        "2": "0.98", 
        "3": "1", 
        "4": "1", 
        "5": "1", 
        "6": "1", 
        "7": "1", 
        "8": "1", 
        "9": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And individualPosts is defined in the price coeffient component:

```
export default function PriceCoefficient() {
  const [individualPosts, setIndividualPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        if (res.status == 200) {//TODO: JSON Encode here?, full repsponse ore response.data as return?
          setIndividualPosts(res.data.discounts.individual.number_of_cars_discount);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PanelHeader size="sm" />
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle tag="h4">PRICE COEFFICIENT</CardTitle>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <Table responsive>
                  <thead className="text-primary">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Customer Type</th>
                      <th>Discount</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <PricePosts
                    individualPosts={individualPosts}
                    loading={loading}
                    error={error}
                  />
                </Table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And in another component, I am just taking individualPosts as a prop where I want to show it on the table:

```
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Individual</td>
            {individualPosts.map((post, index) => (
              <td key={`individual-posts-${index}`}>{post.discount}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>.
```

I dont understand why but I am getting individualPosts.map is not a function and I understand it defined as an object but is there a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Please show all content of your component

Comment: Does it really matter? I define setIndividualPosts(res.data.discounts.individual.number_of_cars_discount);

Comment: It relates to you define state `individualPosts` and how you call `setIndividualPosts`

Comment: Hope it is more clear now, I just edited the question

Comment: `res.data.discounts.individual.number_of_cars_discount` is an object but you are using like an arrry by using `individualPosts.map`

Comment: So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: It depends on what you want to display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use .map on an array. `number_of_cars_discount` is not an array but an object. If you want to iterate through the values of the object use `Object.values(individualPosts).map`, if you want to iterate through keys use `Object.keys(individualPosts).map`.

If you iterate through keys, you can access both key and value within the loop.

```
Object.keys(individualPosts).map(key => {
  console.log(key); //key
  console.log(individualPosts[key]); //value
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: Thats how I tried to loop it {
                Object.keys(individualPosts).map((key) => {
                <td key={key}>{individualPosts[key]}</td>
                })
            }

Comment: There's an issue with your syntax, you aren't returning anything here. Try { Object.keys(individualPosts).map((key) => (<td key={key}>{individualPosts[key]}</td> )) }

Comment: Also make your initial assignment to the state an object. const [individualPosts, setIndividualPosts] = useState({});